# what is the right way to store dates related to a specific column multiple times

Tags: mysql, vb.net, datetime, entity

i feel that i did not even write the question topic correctly because i'm so confused about it 
so here's the thing .. i'm working on a simple application in VB.NET i created Table has columns with (id -name - startdatetime - enddatetime - department)
i want to store that info in a way to let me search for a previous date let's say the info of name from one month a go so i can get that name with the date of that day exactly

i already made it but the problem was every time i insert new data of name and date it will saved on the previous date time so Previous will be erased because will be updated with new one

what make's me so confused is should i create 2 tables with Relation or one is enough to make my app store and keep the past Previous date time associated with the name and department

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will offer some software and database design advice.

Each row in (most) database tables represents some kind of entity in the real world of your application. For example, you might have a table called `department` where each row would hold the department name and location.  The entity here is the department.

Your table, with columns `id`, `startdatetime`, `enddatetime`, `department`, has rows that represent some kind of event. You didn't tell us what kind of event, but it doesn't matter. Let's say the departments take turns sponsoring office coffee hour. The entity for this table is the  sponsored-coffee-hour event.

So, each time there's a sponsored coffee hour, your program will INSERT a new row into your table with the department's name (or id or whatever) and the start and end time.  You most likely will never UPDATE rows in this table, unless you discover, for example that you had the end time wrong  when you first INSERTed the row.

Now you have the record of all the sponsored coffee hours.  You can use your table for various queries. Here's one:  When did each department most recently sponsor coffee hour?

```
       SELECT department, MAX(startdatetime) recent
         FROM tbl 
        GROUP BY department;
```

Your table is enough to represent an entity like this sponsored coffee hour. But, if multiple departments sponsor your coffee hours sometime, you'll need a one-to-many relationship between coffee hours and departments, and therefore another table.

You wrote *every time I insert new data of name and date it is saved on the previous date time ... updated with the new one.* You didn't show your code. From your description I guess you are using UPDATE and changing an existing row rather than using INSERT to put in a new row for a new event. Is it possible your program does that? If so, it's incorrect.

The funny thing about database rows representing real-world events is this: as time goes by you accumulate more and more of them and your tables grow.  That's OK. (You can arrange to DELETE ancient rows, but that's a different topic.)

**Pro tip** Think through the real-world things you're trying to represent knowing that each of those things will get its own row in a table.

I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

thank u so much for the answer and yes you opened my eyes to new things since i'm still learning actually ..
My application is for Patients Records to make records for patients Visits to the facility so if has already record created the user will just add a new visit with new dates and associated with department and doctor name and if has no record so the user will create new record and make a new visit for the patient

you are write i'm using Update but with Update button if want to update the record

```
runcmd("update bsm Set r=" & r.Text & ", nm ='" & nm.Text & "', ino ='" & ino.Text & "', age='" & nt.Text & "', sex='" & ComboBox1.SelectedItem & "', sdat='" & sdat.Text & "', edat='" & edat.Text & "', cp='" & cp.Text & "' , dig='" & dig.Text & "' , dep='" & dep.Text & "' , doc='" & doc.Text & "' , rmk='" & rmk.Text & "' where r=" & r.Text, "Data Is Added Successfully")
```

and i use insert for adding new record

```
Dim strinsert As String = "insert into adm.bsm(r,ino,nm,nt,sex,age,cp,sdat,edat,dig,dep,doc,rmk) VALUES ('" & r.Text & "','" & ino.Text & "','" & nm.Text & "','" & nt.Text & "','" & ComboBox1.SelectedItem & "','" & age.Text & "','" & cp.Text & "','" & sdat.Text & "','" & edat.Text & "','" & dig.Text & "','" & dep.Text & "','" & doc.Text & "','" & rmk.Text & "')"
            Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand(strinsert, conn)
```

Comment: actually i'm still new to codding word ..i still need to learn more about it .. thanks bro:)

Comment: right. you need so-called parameters for your MySqlCommand operations. Read this. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-programming-prepared-preparing.html  and please please be careful with patient data!